# Hyperactive Errors Window in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My Errors window in VS 2008 keeps popping up out of dock, or stealing focus while I'm editing HTML/ASPX.  Is there any remedy for this before I break something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If VS used to behave correctly you can reset all of its settings back to the factory defaults by using:

> **devenv.exe /ResetSettings**

Please note that this will reset *all custom settings* so use it with caution!